# Looking for perfect logic in VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have situation like that, If number is less than 1000, 20 come up
                                                   1001-2000 ,40 come up
                                                  2001-3000, 60 come up in another text box

I am looking for a proper formula.

```
If number <= 1000 Then
    Return 20
ElseIf number <= 2000 Then
    Return 40
ElseIf number <= 3000 Then
    Return 60
ElseIf number <= 4000 Then
    Return 80
ElseIf number <= 5000 Then
    Return 100
ElseIf number <= 6000 Then
    Return 120
ElseIf number <= 7000 Then
    Return 140
ElseIf number <= 8000 Then
    Return 160
ElseIf number <= 9000 Then
    Return 180
ElseIf number <= 10000 Then
    Return 200
ElseIf number <= 11000 Then
    Return 220
ElseIf number <= 12000 Then
    Return 240
ElseIf number <= 13000 Then
    Return 260
ElseIf number <= 14000 Then
    Return 280
ElseIf number <= 15000 Then
    Return 300
End If
```

Comment: Should the last Return be `240` not `220`?

Comment: @Irvin For every case does your result increase by 20?

Comment: @raman a switch statement is not going to change anything here.

Comment: Why does the returned result go back to 40 when number < 5000?

Comment: Use a binary search and a sorted table?

Comment: there is no formula for this, your return values are in this order: 20.40.60.80.40.60.80.100.120.140.160.180.200.220.220 and as you see you have: 60.80.40.60.80.100 , there is no formula on the world for that piece if you x is increasing.

Comment: @IrvinDua: Should the answer for <= 5000 be 100? (and so on for the following results).

Comment: @Jon apologize for that ,please see edit now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your answer:

**VB.Net:**

```
If (number Mod 1000 = 0)
    result = 20 * (number / 1000)
Else
    result = 20 * (number / 1000 + 1)
```

**C#:**

```
if (number % 1000 == 0)
    result = 20 * (number / 1000);
else
    result = 20 * (number / 1000 + 1);
```

Comment: The VB modulo operator is `Mod` not `%`. But anyway [Jon Egerton's anwer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12817191/15639) is much shorter

Comment: Its C# based syntax, i suspect one case is missing in Jon's answer, number % 1000 == 0, not sure as little weak in VB.Net

Answer (score 0):

I can't make it any shorter than:

```
Return ((number \ 1000) + 1) * 20
```

Comment: This won't work. if the number is 1, 20 should be returned.

Comment: you wrong, it's not linear dependence

Comment: Yes - just needed to handle the boudary condition.

Comment: `ElseIf number <= 5000 Then
    Return 40`

Comment: ElseIf number <= 15000 Then
    Return 240
(15000/1000-1)*20!=240

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Yeah - just queried that to see if its the correct requirement or typo, otherwise will delete answer.

Comment: @JonEgerton Thought it was pretty clever. Besides the fact that the code in the question randomly goes back to 40

Comment: @burning_LEGION: Yep - hep handled the arbitrary non-linear element now.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to round the number up to the nearest thousand so we get consistent results.

```
(Math.Ceiling(number/1000)*1000)
```

Then *assuming* you mean to increment by 20 each time (I've seen comments referring to incorrect values), you can divide by 50.

Therefore:

```
Return (Math.Ceiling(number/1000)*1000) / 50
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom `Range` class and a `Dicitonary` to store the range+value:

```
Function GetValue(number As Int32) As Int32
    Dim rangeValues = New Dictionary(Of Range(Of Int32), Int32)
    rangeValues.Add(New Range(Of Int32)(1000), 20)
    rangeValues.Add(New Range(Of Int32)(1001, 2000), 40)
    rangeValues.Add(New Range(Of Int32)(2001, 3000), 60)
    rangeValues.Add(New Range(Of Int32)(3001, 4000), 80)
    rangeValues.Add(New Range(Of Int32)(4001, 5000), 40)
    rangeValues.Add(New Range(Of Int32)(5001, 6000), 40)
    rangeValues.Add(New Range(Of Int32)(6001, 7000), 60)
    rangeValues.Add(New Range(Of Int32)(7001, 8000), 80)
    rangeValues.Add(New Range(Of Int32)(8001, 9000), 100)
    rangeValues.Add(New Range(Of Int32)(9001, 10000), 120)
    rangeValues.Add(New Range(Of Int32)(10001, 11000), 140)
    rangeValues.Add(New Range(Of Int32)(11001, 12000), 160)
    rangeValues.Add(New Range(Of Int32)(12001, 13000), 180)
    rangeValues.Add(New Range(Of Int32)(13001, 14000), 200)
    rangeValues.Add(New Range(Of Int32)(14001, 15000), 220)

    Dim firstMatchingRange = rangeValues.Keys.
        FirstOrDefault(Function(r) r.Minimum <= number AndAlso r.Maximum >= number)
    If firstMatchingRange IsNot Nothing Then
        Return rangeValues(firstMatchingRange)
    Else
        Throw New ArgumentException("invalid number", "number")
    End If
End Function
```

Here's the `Range` class

```
Public Class Range(Of T As IComparable(Of T))
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
    Public Sub New(minimum As T, maximum As T)
        minimum = minimum
        maximum = maximum
    End Sub
    Public Sub New(maximum As T)
        maximum = maximum
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Minimum value of the range
    ''' </summary>
    Public Property Minimum() As T
        Get
            Return m_Minimum
        End Get
        Set(value As T)
            m_Minimum = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Minimum As T

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Maximum value of the range
    ''' </summary>
    Public Property Maximum() As T
        Get
            Return m_Maximum
        End Get
        Set(value As T)
            m_Maximum = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Maximum As T

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Presents the Range in readable format
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <returns>String representation of the Range</returns>
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return [String].Format("[{0} - {1}]", Minimum, Maximum)
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Determines if the range is valid
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <returns>True if range is valid, else false</returns>
    Public Function IsValid() As [Boolean]
        Return Minimum.CompareTo(Maximum) <= 0
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Determines if the provided value is inside the range
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="value">The value to test</param>
    ''' <returns>True if the value is inside Range, else false</returns>
    Public Function ContainsValue(value As T) As [Boolean]
        Return (Minimum.CompareTo(value) <= 0) AndAlso (value.CompareTo(Maximum) <= 0)
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Determines if this Range is inside the bounds of another range
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="Range">The parent range to test on</param>
    ''' <returns>True if range is inclusive, else false</returns>
    Public Function IsInsideRange(Range As Range(Of T)) As [Boolean]
        Return Me.IsValid() AndAlso Range.IsValid() AndAlso Range.ContainsValue(Me.Minimum) AndAlso Range.ContainsValue(Me.Maximum)
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Determines if another range is inside the bounds of this range
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="Range">The child range to test</param>
    ''' <returns>True if range is inside, else false</returns>
    Public Function ContainsRange(Range As Range(Of T)) As [Boolean]
        Return Me.IsValid() AndAlso Range.IsValid() AndAlso Me.ContainsValue(Range.Minimum) AndAlso Me.ContainsValue(Range.Maximum)
    End Function
End Class
```